# jsp portlet tabs sharing the same bean

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tabs, portlet

I need to share the same bean in two tabs defined this way:

```
<fmt:message var="tabNames" key="message.tab.alta" />


<c:set var="tabValues" value="valtab01,valtab02" />


<portlet:renderURL var="URL01" >
        <portlet:param name="action" value="${ServletContextKeys.SC_INSERT}" />
    <portlet:param name="${ServletContextKeys.SC_TAB_INSERT}" value="valtab01" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<portlet:renderURL var="URL02" >
     <portlet:param name="action" value="${ServletContextKeys.SC_ADD_LIST}" />
     <portlet:param name="${ServletContextKeys.SC_TAB_INSERT}" value="valtab02" />
</portlet:renderURL>

<liferay-ui:tabs 
     names="${tabNames}"
     tabsValues="${tabEscrituraValues}"
     param="${ServletContextKeys.SC_TAB_INSERT}"
     url0="${URL01}"
     url1="${URL02}"
     value="${insert_tabs}"
  />
```

So I need to define just one bean in the 2 jsp's representing the 2 tabs:

```
    <form:form id="formInsert" action="action01" method="post" modelAttribute="myBean" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

But I don't know how to make the 2 jsp's share the same bean. 
I need to fill some data of the bean in one tab, and fill one list (within the same bean) on the other tab.
Once all the data is filled, submit from the first tab, and I'll need the whole bean in the controller (The data from the first tab and the list from the second one)
I'm quite new working with portlets, spring and all this stuff, so any help would be great!

Is this possible..?

Comment: Maybe the answer is just... we can't do this...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remember in some way the properties of `modelAttribute` which are not on current tab, you may do this in several ways:

- Persist the `modelAttribute` in session using the `@SessionAttributes` annotation. This is probably the easiest way and it quite literally does what you wanted – makes the JSPs "share" the same bean – but I highly disencourage doing this as a REST advocate, as session is quite an overkill here (not that it's even possible to build RESTful applications with portlets currently).
- Hold the values from the first tab in second tab's form in hidden inputs.
- Hold the values from the first tab in cookies and meld them with second tab's `modelAttribute` upon submission request

The latter two are quite similar I think but for general purposes the hidden inputs would probably be easier to implement (they may require little to no controller code, e.g. for proper validation).

Comment: Ok, actually I'm doing something like this, but, those are kind of workarounds, and I was asking for some propper way to share the same bean. Thanks anyway!